# system.reflection.targetinvocationexception in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asmx

I've created an android app via Xamarin. the app is supposed to connect to sql server through an asmx webservice. I've tested the asmx in my browser and it works well. but the problem is that when I try the app on my android device (not emulator), the following exception occurs:

system.reflection.targetinvocationexception: 'an exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. check innerexception for exception details.'.

now there is a warning that I got after I built my project and it is as follows:

warning XA0105: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for System.EnterpriseServices (v10.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v9.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.

so i'm guessing the exception is due to this warning. I tried increasing the target framework of my project but I got more warnings and errors because api level 29 of the new target framework doesn't seem available. so my question is, is the exception truly the result of the warning? if not what is the solution for such a warning?

Comment: What's the content of the inner exception?

Comment: The "system.reflection.targetinvocationexception" tells you that a method is being called by reflection.  The reflection call could be the source of the error (calling a method by reflection and giving the called method incorrect parameters, for example,) or the error could be in the called method (you gave it correct data types, but a null reference or other exception occurred in the method.)  The only way to tell is to look at the innerexception.

Comment: If you get the more warnings after you set the target framework to android 9.0, you should update all of you nuget packages to the latest.

Comment: how do I reach the inner exception

Comment: You can change the `Xamarin Diagnostics output verbosity` to `Diagnostics` to get the full stack exception like this thread. https://imgur.com/a/K1bChpn